# Embedding rzslider with node.js does not display

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Attempting to embed rzslider (https://github.com/angular-slider/angularjs-slider) with node.js appears to cause the slider to not display.

Here is my setup :

index.html :

```
<html>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angularjs-slider/5.1.0/rzslider.js"></script>

<body>

<script>

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['rzModule']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {



});
</script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<article>
 <rzslider rz-slider-model="10"></rzslider>
 </article>

 </div>
 </body>
```

index.js :

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5001))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))



app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log("Node app is running at localhost:" + app.get('port'))
})
```

Have i setup the slider correctly ?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/slider/rzslider.css"/> ? Also from docs -- jquery is not required.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov yes that fixes, thanks. +1